# What is the creation story of Taweret?

Tags: egyptian

How was the goddess [Taweret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taweret) created? Is there a creation story, or was she just the child of two gods?

Answer (score 1):

Taweret was a so-called "household deity" with first mention in the Old Kingdom, but there never were any large temples or worship centers built in her name. As such, her origin story is not as elaborate as the deities who were associated with large complexes or cities.

Comment: I know that, but what is her creation story?

Comment: As I said: it's a household deity so there seems to be no wide-spread, canonized origin story.